# Ruby fetch api multidimensional hashs filter

Tags: ruby

I'm new. I need to retrieve a specific persons information from this hash. Say I wanted to get the person Micheal Jordans information (**in bold**). I have this code:

```
jdoc.fetch("schedule").fetch("schedule_layers").fetch(users).each do |jsonUser|
puts jsonUser
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I thought it would give all the values of the "users" key but it just spits out the whole thing. How would I be able to get the information thats with Micheal Jordan through a code?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!Please help me understand!

```
"schedule_layers"=>
    [{"name"=>"Layer 1",
      "rendered_schedule_entries"=>[],
      "rendered_coverage_percentage"=>nil,
      "id"=>”A1B2C3”,
      "start"=>"2017-10-09:00:46-05:00",
      "end"=>nil,
      "rotation__start"=>"2017-10-02T20:30:00-05:00",
      "length_seconds"=>36000, 
      "users"=>
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>”0000001”,
           "type"=>"user_reference”,
           "summary"=>”Larry.Bird”,
           "self"=>"https://api.com/users/0000001”,
           "html_url"=>"https://target.com/users/0000001”}}],
      "restrictions"=>
       [{"type"=>"daily_restriction",
         "start_time_of_day"=>”00:30:00",
         "duration_seconds"=>120000}]},
     {"name"=>"Layer 2",
      "schedule_entries"=>[],
      "coverage_percentage"=>nil,
      "id"=>”0000002”,
      "start"=>"2016-12-18:00:51-55:00",
      "end"=>”2017–05-18:12:51-55:00",
      "virtual_start"=>"2016-20-17:00:10-05:00",
      "turn_length_seconds"=>120000,
      "users"=>
        {"user"=>
          **{"id"=>”0000003”,
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>”Micheal.Jordan”,
           "self"=>"https://api.com/users/0000003”,
           "html_url"=>"https://target.com/users/0000003”}},**
        {"user"=>
          {"id"=>”0000004”,
           "type"=>"user_reference",
           "summary"=>”Allen.Iverson”,
           "self"=>"https://api.com/users/0000004”,
           "html_url"=>"https://target.com/users/0000004”}},
           "restrictions"=>[]},
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole data structure? It seems like there are some parts missing. For example, the nesting is invalid, the brackets do not match and you start digging for the values in question with `'schedule'`, but there is no key like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the wrong syntax in `fetch(users)`.

I guess you need to make something like this (I use symbols instead of strings):

```
json_hash = {
  schedule_layers: [
    {
       name: 'l1',
       users: [
         { name: 'u1' },
         { name: 'u2' }
       ]
    },
    {
       name: 'l2',
       users: [
         { name: 'u3' }
       ]
    }
  ]
}

[2] pry(main)> json_hash.fetch(:schedule_layers).flat_map {|x| x[:users] }.each {|x| p x }
{:name=>"u1"}
{:name=>"u2"}
{:name=>"u3"}
=> [{:name=>"u1"}, {:name=>"u2"}, {:name=>"u3"}]
```

To select specific user you can use `select` method:

```
[3] pry(main)> json_hash.fetch(:schedule_layers).flat_map {|x| x[:users] }.select {|x| x[:name] == 'u3' }
=> [{:name=>"u3"}]
```